# Is it possible to create a LifeTimeScope per eventhandler with Autofac and MediatR using a decorator class

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

Is it possible to create a LifeTimeScope per eventhandler with Autofac and MediatR using a decorator class?

So we have two Eventhandlers listening to the same event.
A decorator is supposed to create a LifteTimeScope, resolve the decorated eventhandler and invoke the Handle method of the decorated eventhandler.
I found lot of examples of doing this with CommandHandlers. 
I have played around with code similar to what is shown below.
But I cant make it work. Some posts also suggest making a autofac registrationsource.
Ihave placed a fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/fw4IBw

```
class EventHandlerA : IAsyncNotificationHandler<AnEvent>
{ 
     public void Handle(AnEvent theEvent)
     {
     }
}

class EventHandlerB : IAsyncNotificationHandler<AnEvent>
{ 
     public void Handle(AnEvent theEvent)
     {
     }
}

/// <summary>
///  Wraps inner Notification Handler in Autofac Lifetime scope named 
     PerEventHandlerScope"
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TNotification"></typeparam>
public class LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator<TNotification> :
    IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification> where TNotification : class, 
              IAsyncNotification
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly Type _decoratedType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Const Name of Scope that dependencies can Match using       
     PerMatchingLifeTimeScope(LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator.ScopeName)
    /// </summary>
    public const string ScopeName = LifeTimeScopeKeys.PerHandlerKey;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scope"></param>
    public LifetimeScopeEventHandlerDecorator( ILifetimeScope scope, Type 
          decoratedType )
    {
        _decoratedType = decoratedType;
        _scope = scope;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps inner Notification Handler in Autofac Lifetime scope
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Handle( TNotification notification )
    {
        using ( var perHandlerScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope( 
         LifeTimeScopeKeys.PerHandlerKey ) )
        {
            var decoratedHandler =
   perHandlerScope.ResolveKeyed<IAsyncNotificationHandler<TNotification>>( 
              "IAsyncNotificationHandlerKey" );
            await decoratedHandler.Handle( notification );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question properly, but have you looked at Autofac delegate factories, since Events are just a specific form of a delegate?

Comment: Hi Eris Thx for responding. Yes i have looked somewhat at it. Both autofac automatic support for Func<Service> and also the example where a service also has a delegate factory. I'm just wondering if a Factory would resolve services in the lifetimescope That is created in the decorator. Maybe you suggest that the decorator takes a Func<IAssyncNotificationHandler<TNotification>> as a dpendency in its constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

Finally I figured out a solution. The code can bee seen here  https://dotnetfiddle.net/fw4IBw

It involves the following steps for registration

1. iterate all your assemblies and get all eventHandler types
2. iterate all eventhandler types and register them as 
           Named("EventHandler", eventHandlerType) and with 
           .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope( "PerHandlerKey" );
3. in same loop get notification type
4. in same loop register a
   eventhandlerFactory per eventhandler AsSelf and as
   implementedInterfaces
5. in same loop register only one
   eventHandlerDecorator per notification type .Named(
   "EventHandlerDecorator", interfaceType
   ).AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
6. For MultiInstanceFactory resolve only one decorator for the
   notification  c.ResolveKeyed( "EventHandlerDecorator"...

In EventHandlerDecorator do..

1. Resolve all Factories for NotificationType
2. for each factory create per handler lifetimescope
3. create handler
4. invoke handler